# Birt report error

Tags: report, birt, cognos

Hi we are using **BIRT Cognos v2.1** and while running report we are getting error as below:

```
The following items have errors: 


Table (id = 2874): 
- Can not load the report query: 2874. Errors occurred when generating the 
report document for the report element with ID 2,874. (Element ID:2874) 
Error.ReportQueryLoadingError2 ( 1 time(s) )
detail : org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Can not load 
the report query: 2874. Errors occurred when generating the report document 
for the report element with ID 2,874. (Element ID:2874) at 
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataPresentationEngine.doExecuteQuery(DataPresentationEngine.java:164)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:267)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1939)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.ReportItemExecutor.executeQuery(ReportItemExecutor.java:412)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.TableItemExecutor.doExecute(TableItemExecutor.java:72)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.ReportItemExecutor.execute(ReportItemExecutor.java:294)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.ContainerExecutor.prepareChildExecutor(ContainerExecutor.java:226)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.ContainerExecutor.hasNextChild(ContainerExecutor.java:110)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.hasNextChild(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:86)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.hasNextChild(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:86)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:62)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableLM.java:132)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask$PageRangeRender.render(RenderTask.java:661)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:294)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.renderReport(ReportEngineService.java:1555)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.getPage(BirtViewerReportService.java:204)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.doExecution(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:238)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:105)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor194.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor123.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code of what you're trying to do.  If its a 3rd party app you're just trying to use, this is the wrong place.

Comment: There is not enough detail here to solve the issue.  There is a problem with element 2874, which is a table. Making a wild guess the report is pretty busy as 2874 is a rather high number.  Did the report ever work? Do you know how to figure out which table is 2874? Did adding the table kill the report?

Comment: BIRT and Cognos are completely separate reporting technologies.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error (well, table id was 190), but only when viewing the report externally from Tomcat. The internal or web viewer in BIRT designer was running the report successfully.

The problem ended up being the jdbc driver I was using to connect to the database needed to be copied for birt-viewer in Tomcat even though there was a classpath entry for the driver in the system environment variables.  I copied the jar files for the jdbc driver to "C:\Tomcat6\webapps\birt-viewer\WEB-INF\lib" then restarted the tomcat service.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Datasource connection, edit the datasource check url ,username,password then click the TestConnection button if it is success then you will not get this error.